# Unittesting with jest and IntelliJ

Tags: jestjs

I get an error with a jest unittest in intellij, which I don't know how to solve.

Simple test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import TestComponenent from "./tests/Testcomponent";

test('test TestComponent', () => {
    render(<TestComponenent />);
    expect(screen.getByText("test")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

When running this test in IntelliJ, I get the following error:

● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Class constructor Spec cannot be invoked without 'new'

  102 | function createdPatchedSpec(OriginalSpec, registry) {
  103 |   function PatchedSpec(attrs) {
> 104 |     OriginalSpec.apply(this, arguments);
      |                  ^
  105 |     if (attrs && attrs.id) {
  106 |       registry[attrs.id] = this;
  107 |     }

  at new PatchedSpec (../../../../Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-jasmine.js:104:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/TestComponent.test.js:5:1)
```

Versions:
Jest Package : 3.4.1
Nodejs : 12.16.3

Can someone help ?

Comment: Solved: I installed the newest version of IntelliJ and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I installed the newest Version of IntelliJ.